# Angular using function inside interpolation {{function()}} what does it mean and is it a good practice

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, string-interpolation

**What does using function inside string interpolation mean here?**

```
<p>{{trackTotal()}}</p>
```

For any change, even putting some value in input on same page also it is called:

```
trackTotal()

<input type="text" />
```

Is it a good practice or bad practice to use it this way?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the `trackTotal` does. Since you did not provide code for it, it is hard to tell.

Generally it is better to have a value stored in a component property and compute it only when it's necessary. But using a function is not bad either, if it only does a small computation. You could also use a pipe instead of the function, though.

If implementation is similar to `trackTotal() { return this.data.total }` then it's fine to use it. But creating a getter might be a better option.

If it has any side effects, then not.

```
trackTotal() {
    this.service.startAProcess();
    // or
    return this.total = this.values.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad practice. The change detection in the component will trigger the function call everytime.

To know more about change detection, check this blog https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html#whats-change-detection-anyways